# The Calculate Field tool causes an error when used in a geoprocessing service

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, field-calculator, geoprocessing-service

I wrote a tool that creates a table whith errors and fills an error field.
Then I published it on the server as a geoprocessing service. But when I run it causes an error

[image]

But when I comment `arcpy.CalculateField_management(temp_table_error, "Error_text", "'Раскорчевка должна быть заполнена'", "PYTHON_9.3")` it works great. I don't understand what should I do.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\inetpub.........\GosKontrol_temp.gdb"
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
arcpy.CreateTable_management(arcpy.env.workspace, "Excel_Error_"+str(varOrgname))
temp_table_error=arcpy.env.workspace+"\\Excel_Error_"+str(varOrgname)
arcpy.AddField_management(temp_table_error, "ObjectID_vovl", "LONG", 9)
arcpy.AddField_management(temp_table_error, "Error_text", "TEXT", 255)
UchGoskontr_temp="C:\inetpub\......\GosKontrol_temp.gdb\UchGoskontr_temp"
##########################################################################
expr1=""""Kod_vz"=1 AND "Korch_vz" IS NULL AND "Orgname" = """ + str(varOrgname)

arcpy.MakeTableView_management (UchGoskontr_temp, "stateslyr1", expr1)

#
fieldmappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()
fieldmappings.addTable(temp_table_error)
try:
    fieldmap = fieldmappings.getFieldMap(fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex("ObjectID_vovl"))
    fieldmap.addInputField("stateslyr1", "OBJECTID")
    fieldmappings.replaceFieldMap(fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex("ObjectID_vovl"), fieldmap)
except:
    pass

arcpy.Append_management("stateslyr1",temp_table_error,"NO_TEST",fieldmappings)

arcpy.CalculateField_management(temp_table_error, "Error_text", "'Раскорчевка должна быть заполнена'", "PYTHON_9.3")

arcpy.Delete_management("stateslyr1")
```

Comment: Could you write out the error into the question (instead of a picture). Translated to English would be helpful too.

Comment: @KHibma, there is no description. Just "Failed".

Answer (score 1):

I completely changed my code,made an output to Excel without an additional table and without a field calculator, using SearchCursor. Service worked successfully.

```
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('C:/inetpub/wwwroot/.....Otchet_error_'+str(varOrgname)+'.xlsx')
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet("Errors")

expr1=""""Kod_vz"=1 AND "Korch_vz" IS NULL AND "Orgname" = """ + str(varOrgname)
  
x=0
y=0
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(worklayer,"OBJECTID",expr1)as cursor:
    for row in cursor:
        worksheet1.write_number(x,y, row[0] )
        worksheet1.write(x,y+1, u'Раскорчевка должна быть заполнена')
        x+=1

workbook.close()
```